Run & Extract results of Tasks in Parallel based on Query Param
I have an API where client can request additional data of a resource with a query param as
https://<host>/api/GetAppData?name=appname&getUsers=true&getversion=2.3

Above URL fetches me the appdetails by appname, along with that it fetches the Users & specific version of the app.
However, to get the additional info, I need to do two more calls (I know this is bad but  we are limited with existing infra.)
So, I am trying to do a parallelfetch to the targetAPI with below code.
Task<AppData> appDataTask= myClient.GetAppDataAsync(identifierId, identifierName, version, token);
Task<Users> getUsers= (users.HasValue && users.Value) ? 
    FetchUsers(titleId: appId, token: token) : null;
Task<version> VersionTask= (version.HasValue && version.Value) ?
    FetchVersionApp(titleId: TitleId, token: token) : null;

await Task.WhenAll(appDataTask, getUsers, VersionTask);

AppData app = appDataTask.Result;
AppResponse response = app.ConvertData();
if (getUsers != null) // this means users is requested.
{
    DeployedUsers users= getUsers?.Result;
    response.Users= users;
}
if (VersionTask!= null) // this means AvailableTo is requested.
{
    VersionedApp versionedApp= VersionTask?.Result;
    response.version= versionedApp;
}

How do I achieve this? running this code will throw an ArgumentException.
EDIT:
I tried as following.
bool? usersRequested = mosAppMetadataRequested?.Any(x => x.PathToNavigationProperty.FirstSegment.Identifier.Equals(AAEConstants.ODataConstants.ODataExpandDeployedTo, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
bool? isVersionRequested = mosAppMetadataRequested?.Any(x => x.PathToNavigationProperty.FirstSegment.Identifier.Equals(AAEConstants.ODataConstants.ODataExpandAvailableTo, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

List<Task> appTasks = new();

appTasks.Add(mosAdminApiClient.GetTitlePreviewAsync(identifierId, identifierName, version, token));
if (usersRequested.HasValue && usersRequested.Value)
{
    appTasks.Add(GetDeployDataByTitleIdAsync(titleId: unifiedAppRequest.TitleId, token: token));
}
if (isVersionRequested.HasValue && isVersionRequested.Value)
{
    appTasks.Add(GetAvailableToDataByTitleIdAsync(titleId: unifiedAppRequest.TitleId, token: token));
}

await Task.WhenAll(appTasks);

AppData mosApp = ((Task<AppData>)appTasks[0]).Result;
UnifiedAppResponse response = mosApp.ConvertPreviewToUnifiedAppResponse();
if (usersRequested.HasValue && usersRequested.Value) // this means DeployedTo is requested.
{
    Users mosAppDeployedTo = ((Task<Users>)appTasks[1])?.Result;
    response.DeployedTo = mosAppDeployedTo;
}
if (isVersionRequested.HasValue && isVersionRequested.Value) // this means AvailableTo is requested.
{
    VersionInfo mosAppAvailableTo = ((Task<VersionInfo>)appTasks[2])?.Result;
    response.AvailableTo = mosAppAvailableTo;
}


bith,.. it didnt look like right thing to do and docs also didnt allow me to.. But I dont see a better way as well..

sorry mate thats not the point, you are not being helpful here. please answer if you can or give productive suggestions. its a genuine question.

Alright, I edited the question asking for inputs. please share your thoughts on how to achieve this.

A simple fix: await Task.WhenAll(appDataTask, getUsers ?? Task.CompletedTask, VersionTask ?? Task.CompletedTask);.

Although I would look to refactor this into 3 private methods that return a Task each, that can be passed to WhenAll.

getUsers and VersionTask might return null, you can't pass null to WhenAll. Try to add all tasks in a collection, then filter out null values, and pass the collection to WhenAll.Or simply do a positive check for each one, and if true then add it to the collection.

But @iSR5, if we add to a collection and filter out nulls, how do we extract results and know that this item's result is related to this task?  cant depend on index of the item then right?

@Programmerzzz you can use an indexed collection such as Array or List<T>, and get the results by index.

Thats what I tried as well. Please see my edits and let me know if that looks correct on what you are also suggesting as well.
